# How do I get the image file to be properly labeled when trying to produce topk predictions on an image?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to produce a graph of the top 5 predictions from a image classifier for any given image.  My files are organized as such:

- Test/ --> class_name/ --> image_number 
  for example,
- Test/ --> chocolate/ --> 0015254.jpg

When I use the following code, I can't get the class name to redirect to print, it gives an error that results in every class being outputted (shown below).

class_to_idx:

```
classes = os.listdir(train_folder)
classes.sort()
#print(classes)
label_mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(classes)}

class_to_idx = {classes[i]: i for i in range(len(classes))}
```

Here is the code to generate an image and print its top5 predictions:

```
def sanity_check(path):

  imagepath = test_folder + path
  image = process_image(imagepath)

  plot = imshow(image, ax = plt)
  plot.axis('off')
  plot.title(class_to_idx[str(classes)])
  plot.show()

  axes = predict(imagepath, model)

  yaxis = [class_to_idx[str(i)] for i in np.array(axes[1][0].cpu())]
  y_pos = np.arange(len(yaxis))
  xaxis = np.array(axes[0][0].cpu().numpy())   

  plt.barh(y_pos, xaxis)
  plt.xlabel('probability')
  plt.yticks(y_pos, yaxis)
  plt.title('probability of {} classification'.format(name))

  plt.show()

path = '/chocolate_mousse/1379570.jpg'
sanity_check(path)
```

Here is the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-5747e27aee19> in <module>()
      1 path = '/chocolate_mousse/1379570.jpg'
----> 2 sanity_check(path, name = 'Chocolate Mousse')

<ipython-input-62-295700419574> in sanity_check(path, name)
      7   plot = imshow(image, ax = plt)
      8   plot.axis('off')
----> 9   plot.title(class_to_idx[str(classes)])
     10   plot.show()
     11 

KeyError: "['apple_pie', 'baby_back_ribs', 'baklava', 'beef_carpaccio', 'beef_tartare', 'beet_salad', 'beignets', .... etc
```

Comment: `class_to_idx` does not have a member where the key is the string of all `classes`. What you want to name your plot as in `plot.title(class_to_idx[str(classes)])`?

Comment: I would like it to be the class name of the image. The class name in the example I gave would be "chocolate_mousse". I added the code for class_to_idx in my original question, since that code may also be part of the problem.  I also changed sanity_check(path, name) to just sanity_check(path) since name is what I want from plot.title.

Comment: As your `path` already contains the class name, can you just use it as `plot.title(path.split('/')[1])`?

Comment: Thank you that worked!  How did you know to put the [1] there, what does it signify?

Comment: `path.split('/')` returns a list of strings separated by the character `'/'`. In your case it returns `['','chocolate_mousse','1379570.jpg']`, so `path.split('/')[1]` gives `'chocolate_mousse'`.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.  Thank you for explaining.